any scenario's to use @Transactional annotation at Repository delete method?
I am reveiewing the code for one of the senior member for the first peer review so he added @Transactional annotation at custom repository with delete method. The custom Repository delete method is being called in one of the Asychronous service method.
public interface DeviceRepository extends 
 JpaRepository<Device, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Device> {
 
    @Transactional
    void deleteDeviceByDeviceName(String deviceName);
 }

do we need to use @Transactional method Repository layer, will impact anything like performanance.
any scenario's to use @Transactional annotation at JPA Repository layer?

No transaction no delete. So either the service needs to drive the transaction or it must be here. A transaction is not about performance it is about persisting changes in the database, without one nothing will happen.

Everything is explained in the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/transactions.html#transactional-query-methods
In short, you must use @Transactional to run them transactional.

That method can delete multiple rows from table. If you want it to hapen in transaction you have to say that.
Granted you rarely see @Transactional in repository, usually it is on service layer.
